# Scroll View in an Universal Xcode Project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, scrollview

I am creating an Universal app that has a scroll view.

The app runs fine for both the iPhone and iPad.  However the scroll view is set to the iPad dimensions.  So when i run the app on the iPhone the scroll view is still set for the iPad.

Any way I can change that?

Comment: Have you tried changing the frame on viewDidLoad for the view controller?

Comment: Use the screen size to calculate the size needed for the scroll view rather then hard coding it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [myScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}else{
    [myScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
}
```

Of course you'll have to make adjustments to the scroll view's content size as well.

Comment: Thank you everyone. NSPostWhenIdle code was awesome. I modified it a little.  Here is what I used.  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [TextScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 750)];
    }else{
        [TextScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1100)];
    }
    
    [TextScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];